# GCP Cloud Function PubSub not passing message to topic

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to write a GCP Cloud Function which collects some data from an API call then stores selected data points in Firestore. I also would like to pass the event IDs to PubSub topic so that I can use them in other Cloud Functions.

So far I have the following:

```
import base64
import os
import requests
import json
from firebase_admin import firestore
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# FIRESTORE DATABASE
db = firestore.Client(project='puntau')

# API INFO
Base_url = 'https://xxxx.net/v1/feeds/sportsbookv2'
Sport_id = 'xxxx'
AppID = 'xxxx'
AppKey = 'xxxx'
Country = 'en_AU'
Site = 'www.xxxx.com.au'


# Publishes a message to a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
def event_info(self):

    event_ids = []

    link = f'{Base_url}/event/group/{Sport_id}.json?app_id={AppID}&app_key={AppKey}&local={Country}&site={Site}'
    print(link)
    # Request data from link as 'str'
    data = requests.get(link).text
    # convert 'str' to Json
    data = json.loads(data)
    # JSON PARSE
    for event_data in data['events']:
        if event_data['path'][1]['name'] == 'NBA' and event_data['groupId'] == 1000093652 and 'MATCH' in event_data['tags']:
            competition = event_data['group']
            event_id = event_data['id']
            event_name = event_data['name']
            event_start = event_data['start']
            event_status = event_data['state']

            print(f'{competition} {event_id} {event_name} {event_start} {event_status}')

            event_ids.append(event_id)

            # WRITE TO FIRESTORE
            doc_ref = db.collection(u'xxxx_au').document(u'basketball_nba').collection(u'event_info').document(f'{event_id}')
            doc_ref.set({
                u'competition': competition,
                u'event_id': event_id,
                u'event_name': event_name,
                u'event_start': event_start,
                u'event_status': event_status,
                u'timestamp': firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP,
            })

    return str(event_ids)

    event_keys = str(event_ids)

    project_id = 'puntau'
    topic_id = 'unibet_basketball_nba'

    # Instantiates a Pub/Sub client
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)

    data = event_keys.encode('utf-8')

    # Publishes a message to a Pub/Sub topic
    future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
    print(future.result())
```

output in the logs:

```
[1018936416, 1018936327, 1018936419, 1018936392, 1018936473, 1018936375, 1018936471]
```

Plus the data for Firestore is captured and stored no issue.

The problem I have is that the output above (event_keys) are not passed to the PubSub topic.

Is there an issue with my code or with the setup of the function in GCP?

Comment: what's the content of the message if there isn't your data?

Comment: trying to pass "event_ids" as "event_keys" to pubsub. I then want to use those event_keys in API calls as variables in URLs in other cloud functions.

Comment: this what the event_keys looks like [1018936416, 1018936327, 1018936419, 1018936392, 1018936473, 1018936375, 1018936471]

Comment: Ok for what you send, but what you recieved? What's the message content?

Comment: @DrewS Can you confirm whether the code below the `return` statement is executing or not and whether `event_keys` contains the data or not?

Comment: I am getting no message when i pull messages in pubsub section of GCP console.

Comment: when i print `event_keys = str(event_ids)

    print(event_keys)` i get no output, so that might be the issue. is it an indentation issue?

Comment: but why would the event keys be appearing in the logs?

Comment: @DrewS  Can you try to move the return statement in last and try it again.

Comment: i removed it and it seemd to have fixed the issue. can see message in pub/sub now. thanks.

Comment: @DrewS Glad to hear the issue is resolved. I have posted an answer with the info gathered from here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have written PubSub code below the `return` statement the code was not executing.After rearranging the code it should be working as expected.

From the comments it is clear that after modifying the code it is working as intended.